# Compute, column arrange and select `within` data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, plyr

I often have a dataframe from some computation which I want to cleanup, rename and column-arrange before outputting. All versions below work, the simple `data.frame` comes closest.

Is there a way to combine the within-dataframe computation of `within` and `mutate` with the column order preservation of `data.frame()`, without the additional and redundant [,....] at the end?

```
library(plyr) 

# Given this chaotically named data.frame
d = expand.grid(VISIT=as.factor(1:2),Biochem=letters[1:2],time=1:5,
                subj=as.factor(1:3))
d$Value1 =round(rnorm(nrow(d)),2)
d$val2 = round(rnorm(nrow(d)),2)

# I would like to cleanup, compute and rearrange columns

# Simple and almost perfect
dDataframe = with(d, data.frame(
  biochem = Biochem,
  subj = subj,
  visit = VISIT,
  value1 = Value1*3 
))
# This simple solution is almost perfect, 
# but requires one more line
dDataframe$value2 = dDataframe$value1*d$val2

# For the following methods I have to reorder 
# and select in a second step

# use mutate from plyr to allow computation on computed values,
# which transform cannot do.
dMutate =   mutate(d,
  biochem = Biochem,
  subj = subj,
  visit = VISIT,
  value1 = Value1*3, #assume this is a time consuming function
  value2 = value1*val2
  # Could set fields = NULL here to remove,
  # but this does not help getting column order
)[,c("biochem","subj","visit","value1","value2")]

# use within. Same problem, order not preserved
dWithin = within(d, {
  biochem = Biochem
  subj = subj
  visit = VISIT
  value1 = Value1*3
  value2 = value1*val2       
})[,c("biochem","subj","visit","value1","value2")]


all.equal(dDataframe,dWithin)
all.equal(dDataframe,dMutate)
```

Comment: in your simple dataframe, I would use `names(d)<-tolower(names(d))` if more col names have upper case

Comment: You can use trick introduced by mnel with function with. ... value1 = val1 <- Value1*3, value2 = val1*val2 ...

Comment: @mnel 's trick was an interesting one I was not aware of, but nothing beats `summarize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `summarize` (or `summarise`) from the `plyr` package. From the doc:

> Summarise works in an analagous way to transform, except instead of adding columns to an existing data frame, it creates a new data frame. [...]

For your example:

```
library(plyr)
summarize(d,
  biochem = Biochem,
  subj    = subj,
  visit   = VISIT,
  value1  = Value1 * 3,
  value2  = value1 * val2       
)
```

Comment: I knew I had missed something obvious!

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to move over to `data.table`, then you can perform (most) of these actions by reference and avoid the copying associated with `[<-.data.frame` and `$<-.data.frame`

`setnames` will rename a `data.table`. `setcolorder` will reorder a `data.table` and `:=` will assign by reference.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(d)
# rename to lowercase only
setnames(DT, old = names(DT), new = tolower(names(DT))
# reassign using `:=`
# note the use of `value1<-value1` to allow later use. 
# This will not be necessary once FR1492 has been implemented
# setting to NULL removes these columns
DT[, `:=`(value1 =value1<- value1*3, 
         value2  = value1 * val2, 
         val2 = NULL, time = NULL )]
setcolorder(DT, c("biochem","subj","visit","value1","value2"))
```

---

If you don't care as much about memory efficiency, and just wish to use `data.table` for syntax, then

```
DT <- data.table(d)
DT[,list(  biochem = Biochem,   
    subj    = subj,
   visit   = VISIT,
   value1 = value1  <- Value1 * 3,
   value2  = value1 * val2       
   )]
```

Will work.

Comment: This is much more verbose than the simple `data.frame` solution. For efficiency, it might be good, but `summarize` definitively is the winner in clarity.

Comment: @DieterMenne -- I've added a simpler (less memory efficient) approach

Comment: That one looks much better. I remember: never forget the `list` in `data.table`.